# Adding a column to a Pandas dataframe that results from a call to a class method that uses row values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that looks as follows:

```
,calculation_date,opt_type,strike_price,maturity_date,underlying_price,risk_free_rate,implied_volatility,dividend_rate
0,2022-01-10 01:24:00,Call,90000,2022-12-30,41693.21,0.01,0.804194,0.01
1,2022-01-10 01:24:00,Call,90000,2022-12-30,41693.21,0.01,0.840400,0.01
2,2022-01-10 01:25:00,Put,15000,2022-06-24,41684.7,0.01,0.863425,0.01
3,2022-01-10 01:25:00,Put,15000,2022-06-24,41684.7,0.01,0.878962,0.01
4,2022-01-10 01:25:00,Put,20000,2022-06-24,41684.7,0.01,0.806613,0.01
```

The resulting Pandas dataframe looks as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('options.csv',
                 header=0,
                 names=['idx',
                        'calculation_date',
                        'opt_type',
                        'strike_price', 
                        'maturity_date', 
                        'underlying_price', 
                        'risk_free_rate', 
                        'implied_vol', 
                        'dividend_rate'],
                 parse_dates=True
                )

df

    idx calculation_date     opt_type   strike_price    maturity_date   underlying_price    risk_free_rate  implied_vol dividend_rate   
0   0   2022-01-10 01:24:00  Call       90000           2022-12-30      41693.21            0.01            0.804194    0.01
1   1   2022-01-10 01:24:00  Call       90000           2022-12-30      41693.21            0.01            0.840400    0.01
2   2   2022-01-10 01:25:00  Put        15000           2022-06-24      41684.70            0.01            0.863425    0.01
3   3   2022-01-10 01:25:00  Put        15000           2022-06-24      41684.70            0.01            0.878962    0.01
4   4   2022-01-10 01:25:00  Put        20000           2022-06-24      41684.70            0.01            0.806613    0.01
```

Next, I have a class that looks as follows:

```
import QuantLib as ql

class European_Option:

    day_count = ql.Actual365Fixed()
    calendar = ql.UnitedStates()

    def __init__(
        self,
        underlying_price,
        strike_price,
        maturity_date,
        risk_free_rate,
        implied_volatility,
        calculation_date,
        dividend_rate,
    ):
        self.underlying_price = underlying_price
        self.strike_price = strike_price
        self.maturity_date = ql.Date(maturity_date, "%d-%m-%Y")
        self.risk_free_rate = risk_free_rate
        self.implied_volatility = implied_volatility
        self.calculation_date = ql.Date(calculation_date, "%d-%m-%Y")
        self.dividend_rate = dividend_rate

        self.option_type = ql.Option.Call

        self.payoff = ql.PlainVanillaPayoff(self.option_type, self.strike_price)

        self.exercise = ql.EuropeanExercise(self.maturity_date)
        self.european_option = ql.VanillaOption(self.payoff, self.exercise)

        self.spot_handle = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(self.underlying_price))

        self.flat_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(
            ql.FlatForward(self.calculation_date, self.risk_free_rate, self.day_count)
        )

        self.dividend_yield = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(
            ql.FlatForward(self.calculation_date, self.dividend_rate, self.day_count)
        )

        self.flat_vol_ts = ql.BlackVolTermStructureHandle(
            ql.BlackConstantVol(
                self.calculation_date,
                self.calendar,
                self.implied_volatility,
                self.day_count,
            )
        )

        self.bsm_process = ql.BlackScholesMertonProcess(
            self.spot_handle, self.dividend_yield, self.flat_ts, self.flat_vol_ts
        )

    def get_bs_price(self):
        self.european_option.setPricingEngine(ql.AnalyticEuropeanEngine(self.bsm_process))
        bs_price = self.european_option.NPV() / self.underlying_price
        return bs_price

    def get_delta(self):
        delta = self.european_option.delta()
        return delta

    def get_gamma(self):
        gamma = self.european_option.gamma()
        return gamma

    def get_vega(self):
        vega = self.european_option.vega()
        return vega

    def get_theta(self):
        theta = self.european_option.theta()
        return theta
```

With this class, we can use methods such as `get_bs_price()` and `get_delta` to get information about each row such as `bs_price` and `delta`, respectively.

For example, using the first row in the `df`, we can call:

```
foo = European_Option('Call',
                      41693.21,
                      90000,
                      '30-12-2022',
                      0.01,
                      0.804194,
                      '10-01-2022',
                      0.01
                        )

foo.get_bs_price()
0.09646261334373059

foo.get_delta()
0.279722212144296
```

**Question**:  how do we pass the relevant values in each row to the `get_bs_price()` and `get_delta()` methods to return the resulting values of these functions as new columns?

(I believe we can use `apply()` or `map()`, but I'm not sure how to instantiate each row)

The desired `df` would look as follows:

```
    idx calculation_date     opt_type   strike_price    maturity_date   underlying_price    risk_free_rate  implied_vol dividend_rate   bs_price                delta
0   0   2022-01-10 01:24:00  Call       90000           2022-12-30      41693.21            0.01            0.804194    0.01            0.09646261334373059     0.279722212144296
1   1   2022-01-10 01:24:00  Call       90000           2022-12-30      41693.21            0.01            0.840400    0.01
2   2   2022-01-10 01:25:00  Put        15000           2022-06-24      41684.70            0.01            0.863425    0.01
3   3   2022-01-10 01:25:00  Put        15000           2022-06-24      41684.70            0.01            0.878962    0.01
4   4   2022-01-10 01:25:00  Put        20000           2022-06-24      41684.70            0.01            0.806613    0.01
```

Comment: simply use a for and iterate through every row in the dataframe and inside for loop create object of class using row data and find the bs_price and delta and then store them in lists. after the for you can simply assign these lists to columns in the dataframe

Comment: @NALLAPANENIVENKATESHCHOWDARY -- the production data is millions of rows.  Would your approach be more performant than, say, using `apply()` or `map()`? (none of these approaches I'm 100% clear on how to implement, by the way)

Comment: for using apply() or map() we need functions. so try converting class methods to normal functions and use those functions in apply()